# TokenTimelock gives out of gas errors when deployed within Truffle 4.0.1

Tags: truffle, out-of-gas, truffle-migration, gas-estimate, openzeppelin

I'm trying to deploy a contract using [Truffle v4.0.1](http://truffleframework.com), within Truffle's own console but I keep getting `out of gas` errors.

The constructor looks like:

```
function MyAwesomeCrowdsale(
    uint64 _startTime,
    uint64 _endTime,
    uint256 _rate,
    uint256 _presaleRate,
    address _wallet,
    address _foundationPool,
    address _foundersPool,
    address _legalExpensesWallet,
    uint256 _goal
) public
{
    require(_endTime > _startTime);
    require(_rate > 0);
    require(_wallet != 0x0);

    token = new MyAwesomeToken(TOTAL_SUPPLY_CAP);
    // mints all tokens and gives them to the crowdsale
    token.mint(address(this), TOTAL_SUPPLY_CAP);
    token.finishMinting();

    startTime = _startTime;
    endTime = _endTime;
    rate = _rate;
    presaleRate = _presaleRate;
    wallet = _wallet;
    goal = _goal;

    vault = new MyAwesomeRefundVault(wallet);

    foundationPool = _foundationPool;
    foundersPool = _foundersPool;
    legalExpensesWallet = _legalExpensesWallet;

    // Set timelocks to 1 year after startTime
    uint64 unlockAt = uint64(startTime + 31622400);
    timelockFounders = new TokenTimelock(token, foundersPool, unlockAt);

    distributeInitialFunds();
}
```

I hit `out of gas` error at the line:

```
timelockFounders = new TokenTimelock(token, foundersPool, unlockAt);
```

`TokenTimelock` is imported from `zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/TokenTimelock.sol`

If I comment that out then everything deploys just fine, but with that line in there, no amount of messing about with default `gas` and `gasPrice` values helps at all.

How can I reliably estimate the `gas` needed to deploy this contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truffle 4.0 has optimization turned off by default, so you'll probably want to both increase supplied gas and turn optimization on so the gas used on creation is considerably reduced:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 4500000
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside truffle.js, add more gas:

```
module.exports = {
  migrations_directory: "./migrations",
  networks: {
        rinkeby: {
          provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/"),
          gas: 4500000,
          network_id: 4
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm specifically trying to do this within the `truffle console` not an external blockchain.